# Relatively compactness of uniformly limited measures in variation w.r.t. weak convergence

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence, bounded-variation

Let $f_n(x).dx$ be measures with density wrt Lebesgue measure, $f_n$ derivable, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in uniform norm; $\ n \rightarrow \infty$.

Assume that they are uniformly limited in variation, i.e. $\exists M:\ \int |Df_n|(dx)<M\ \forall n$, where $Df$ is the distributional derivative of $f$.

This means $\forall \phi \in {C_c}^1(\mathbb{R}^n),\ \int f(x)\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta x_i} (x)dx=\int\phi(x)(D_i f)(dx)$.

Than there is a subsuccession $f_{k_n}\ n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_{k_n}(x).dx$ converges weakly. How can i show it?

Original De Giorgi paper says it's an "easy" consequence of a theorem of de La Vallee Poussin.

Notice that i have very few confidence with this field, so please try to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: The notions of Lebesgue measure, distributional derivative, and weak convergence are themselves not "elementary," so I'm not sure how you expect an answer to this question to be such.

Comment: You are right, i need answers to be detailful, with all implications needed, or with references.